# Issue while importing nltk package in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error, nltk, python-import

When I type

```
import nltk
```

in the Python interpreter, it gives me this --

```
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    from collocations import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/collocations.py", line 38, in <module>
    from nltk.metrics import ContingencyMeasures, BigramAssocMeasures, TrigramAssocMeasures
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/metrics/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from nltk.metrics.scores import          (accuracy, precision, recall, f_measure,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/metrics/scores.py", line 16, in <module>
    from scipy.stats.stats import betai
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from stats import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 198, in <module>
    import distributions
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.py", line 87, in <module>
    from new import instancemethod
  File "new.py", line 3

        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I took a look at new.py which I found in /usr/lib/python2.7/ and found everything ok.

```
"""Create new objects of various types. 
 Deprecated.This module is no longer required except for backward compatibility.
 Objects of most types can now be created by calling the type object.
"""
from warnings import warnpy3k
warnpy3k("The 'new' module has been removed in Python 3.0; use the 'types' "
            "module instead.", stacklevel=2)
del warnpy3k

from types import ClassType as classobj
from types import FunctionType as function
from types import InstanceType as instance
from types import MethodType as instancemethod
from types import ModuleType as module

from types import CodeType as code
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a *local* file named `new.py`. Check your current directory and rename it or delete it.

You can see this in the traceback:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.py", line 87, in <module>
    from new import instancemethod
  File "new.py", line 3
```

The preceding module has a full filepath, but the `new.py` file does not, making it a local file that is shadowing the relative import in `scipy.stats.distributions`.

Comment: @Martijn Thanks, the above problem is solved. Unfortunately, now I am getting the following error -->>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 161, in <module>
    from downloader import download, download_shell
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 180, in <module>
    urllib2 = nltk.internals.import_from_stdlib('urllib2')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'internals'

Comment: You have a `nltk.py` file as well, again locally.